# How to create a python menu where the options are selectable and unselectable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a python menu that has numbered menu options, and when you select one of these options, an x appears next to it to show that, that particular option has been selected. Then, if the user selects the option again, I want the x to disappear to show that that option is no longer selected.

Here are example images of what I want my program to do:

1. [The Menu is blank.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkpUG.png)
2. [The option that was selected has a little x next to it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Virty.png)
3. [When selected again, the option becomes blank again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK1xK.png)

Here is my test code so far:

```
test = print("1. Normal Character Generator({})".format(""))
test2 = print("2. Advanded Appearance Generator({})".format(""))


def normalGenerationTrue():
    test = print("1. Normal Character Generator({})".format("X"))


while True:
    try:
        selection = int(input("Please choose one of the menu options.\n"))

        if selection == 1:
            normalGenerationTrue()
            new = input("Would you like to make another selection?").lower()
            if new == "yes":
                print(test)
            elif new == "no":
                break
        elif selection == 2:
            advancedGenerationTrue()
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Choice. Enter one of the menu numbers.")
            test = print("1. Normal Character Generator({})".format(""))
            test2 = print("2. Advanded Appearance Generator({})".format(""))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Choice. Enter one of the menu numbers.")
```

Comment: first you should keep in some variable  which element was selected and later you should use `if/else`with every element on menu to check if it need `X` or not. OR you should keep this information on some list - for every element keep `X` or empty string.

Comment: `print()` always gives `None` - so assigning `test = print(...)` is useless because it always means `test = None`. If you want to assign text to variable then you should do it directly `test = "1....".format("")`. And later print it `print(test)`. But you should use variables `"1....".format(variable_for_menu_1)` to change it.

Comment: BTW: in many programs I see (and I prefer) `X`  at the beginning of line in `[ ]` - like `[X] 1. ...` and in next line `[ ] 2. ...` - this way all `[X]` `[ ]` are in the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep menu on list

```
menu = [
   "1. Normal Character Generator",
   "2. Advanded Appearance Generator",
]
```

And keep last selection in variable (`0` means not seletion)

```
selected = 0
```

And later you can use both values to display menu with or without `X`

```
def display_menu(menu, selected):
    for number, item in enumerate(menu, 1):
        if number == selected:
            print('(X)', item)
        else:
            print('( )', item)
```

And later you have to assign new value to `selected`

```
while True:
    display_menu(menu, selected)

    try:
        # don't assign directly to `selected` because user may choose wrong number
        new_selection = int(input("Please choose one of the menu options.\n"))

        if new_selection in (1, 2):
            # assign to `selected` when user choose correct number
            selected = new_selection

            display_menu(menu, selected)
 
            new = input("Would you like to make another selection? [Y/n]").lower()

            if new in ("n", "no"):
                break
        else:
            print("Invalid Choice. Enter one of the menu numbers.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Choice. Enter one of the menu numbers.")
```

**BTW:**

I put `(X)` `( )` at the beginning of line because it is more readable - and many programs put it at the beginning of line (similar to checkboxes in GUIs).

In second question I check also `n` because it simpler to write only `n` instead of `no`. And many programs do this.

I also use text `[Y/n]` (similar to other programs) to show possible selection - `n` or `y`. Upper `Y` is popular method to inform user that it is default value which will be used if he/she press only `Enter` (without typing `y`).

---

Full code:

```
menu = [
    "1. Normal Character Generator",
    "2. Advanded Appearance Generator",
]

selected = 0

def display_menu(menu, selected):
    for number, item in enumerate(menu, 1):
        if number == selected:
            print('(X)', item)
        else:
            print('( )', item)
    
while True:
    display_menu(menu, selected)

    try:
        # don't assign directly to `selected` because user can choose wrong number
        new_selection = int(input("Please choose one of the menu options.\n>> "))

        if new_selection in (1, 2):
            # assign to `selected` because it it correct number
            selected = new_selection

            display_menu(menu, selected)
 
            new = input("Would you like to make another selection? [Y/n]\n>> ").lower()

            if new in ("n", "no"):
                break
        else:
            print("Invalid Choice. Enter one of the menu numbers.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Choice. Enter one of the menu numbers.")
```

Result:

```
( ) 1. Normal Character Generator
( ) 2. Advanded Appearance Generator
Please choose one of the menu options.
>> 1
(X) 1. Normal Character Generator
( ) 2. Advanded Appearance Generator
Would you like to make another selection? [Y/n]
>> 
(X) 1. Normal Character Generator
( ) 2. Advanded Appearance Generator
Please choose one of the menu options.
>> 2
( ) 1. Normal Character Generator
(X) 2. Advanded Appearance Generator
Would you like to make another selection? [Y/n]
>> y
( ) 1. Normal Character Generator
(X) 2. Advanded Appearance Generator
Please choose one of the menu options.
>> 1
(X) 1. Normal Character Generator
( ) 2. Advanded Appearance Generator
Would you like to make another selection? [Y/n]
>> n
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm kinda surprised I didn't find similar problems to mine on the internet, I was sure that there would be loads of these command line menu problems. Anyways though, thanks again for your help.